# what destination << source.rdbuf(); is doing ? why too many open close

Tags: c++

```
if (!source.is_open() || !destination.is_open()) 
{   
    if (source.is_open())
    {source.close();
    }
    if (destination.is_open())
    {destination.close();
    }
    return -1;
}
destination << source.rdbuf();
source.close();
destination.close();
return  0;
```

Comment: moving from one buffer to another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`destination` is presumably an output character stream. `<<` is a binary operator which inserts the right hand operand into the output stream that is the left hand operand. In this case, the result of `source.rdbuf()` is inserted.

`source.rdbuf()` is a function call. `rdbuf` is a member function of `source`. `source` is presumably in input character stream. Under  this assumption, the behaviour of `rdbuf` is as per documentation:

> Returns the associated stream buffer.

The behaviour of inserting a stream buffer into an output stream is as per documentation:

> extracts characters from the input sequence controlled by [the stream buffer] and inserts them into [the output stream] until one of the following conditions
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - ...

As an example, if `destination` is a string stream, and `source` is a file stream, then after the operation the string within the buffer of the string stream will contain the entire contents of the file.